# Google Cloud HTTP function - Why is the function so picky for cURL json format

Tags: json, http, curl, google-cloud-platform, xmlhttprequest

I could use some help understanding why my Google Cloud Function is so picky about the format that I pass in JSON.

I was following this guide from [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests). The very first example on the page has you create a function exactly like this:

```
exports.helloHttp = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${escapeHtml(req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World')}!`);
};
```

Then they ask you to trigger it via curl:

```
curl -X POST HTTP_TRIGGER_ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"name":"Jane"}'
```

To my surprise I could not get it to work, I have spent a lot of time playing around with params and options until this worked for me:

```
curl -X POST HTTP_TRIGGER_ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d {\"name\":\"Jane\"}
```

I am using a Windows 10 machine and on a terminal that has node(10) installed(In case that matters).

**1.** What makes me need to remove the single quotes and add the backslashes, does this format have a name or keywords?

**2.** Can the answer to question 1 be used in a vanilla javascript XMLHttpRequest? As I have not been able to apply my curl modifications successfully.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "myFunctionURL");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(`{\"name\":\"Jane"}`);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
   console.log('response: ', JSON.stringify(xhr), ' status: ', xhr.status);
 }
}
```

I have tried passing numerous params into the send including:

```
var body = {};
body.name = 'Jane';
*passing body into xhr.send*

var body = `{\"name\",\"Jane\"};
*passing body into xhr.send*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not Google Cloud Function, it's the Windows Version of CURL command which has an issue with single quotes when posting JSON payload.

Take a look at the following threads which seem to discuss the same issues but in a different context:

https://superuser.com/questions/1016710/how-to-make-a-curl-post-call-in-windows
https://superuser.com/questions/1291352/curl-command-runs-in-linux-but-not-windows-2008